# $A$ can walk certain distance in $20$ days when he rests $6$ hours a day

Tags: arithmetic, word-problem

**Problem :** $A$ can walk certain distance in $20$ days when he rests $6$ hours a day. How long will he take to walk the distance twice as fats and resting twice as long each day ?

**Solution :**  let distance be $x$

time taken without rest  $=20 -5 =15$ days

speed =$ \frac {x}{15}$

new speed = $ \frac {2x}{15}$

distance =  $x$

time  taken without rest=  $ \frac {15x}{2x}$

=7.5

time taken with rest $=12 *7 =84$ hours

$3.5$days

total time taken $=7.5 +3.5=11$ days

But this answer is not correct.

Help me

Comment: The new version starts OK. There are now $12$ hours a day of rest, so if daily walking comes after the rest, the $7.5$ days of actual walking will be spread over $15$ days.

Comment: but ans is not $15 $ days

Comment: Then my interpretation of the question is not the intended one. Depends when rest is. If at the end of the day then the person reaches destination in $14.5$ days.

Comment: Some speculation: Is the new distance twice the old distance, as in "how long will he take to walk _twice_ the distance ..."? (because everything else was doubled) If it is, the answer would be $30$ days, matching one of the options.

Comment: i don't know. read question carefully.question is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When he rests $6$ hours a day, that would mean he would walk $24-6=18$ hours a day, or $\frac{18}{24}=\frac{3}{4}$ days everyday. He does this for $20$ days, so the total time he walks would be $20 \times \frac{3}{4} = 15$ days.

If the distance he walks is $x$, his speed would be $\frac{x}{15}$.

Then his new speed is $\frac{x}{15}\times{2}=\frac{2x}{15}$

He walks for the same distance, so the product between the new speed and the new time would still be $x$: (remember: $\frac{\text{distance}}{\text{time}}=\text{speed}$)

$$
\frac{x}{t}=\frac{2x}{15} \\x \times 15 = 2x \times t \\ t = \frac{15x}{2x}=\frac{15}{2}
$$
This means it would take him $\frac{15}{2}$ days of nonstop walking to walk the same distance.

But he rests twice more than he did before, so he would walk $24-6\times2 = 12$ hours a day, or $\frac{12}{24}=\frac 1 2$ day everyday. That is, he would walk $\frac{1}{2}$ of some number of days, and at the end, he would have walked for $\frac{15}{2}$ days. Then:

$$
\text{Total days} \times \frac{1}{2} = \frac{15}{2} \\
\text{Total days} = 15 \text{ days}
$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: its a MCQ question. Answer is one of them $60,24,30,40$ or $80$ days

Comment: @rst That is odd; it seems that others have agreed that the answer should be $15$.

Comment: I think options are wrong

Answer (score -1):

20 x 18 x 1(let speed is 1km/hr)  x 2(distance twice) = D(Number of days) x 12 x 1(speed)

D = 60 days

Comment: It would be good to provide more detail.